# Add multiple variables (Digital Download Links) to an email body with PHP

Tags: php, email, variables, paypal, paypal-ipn

If a user purchases item 'a' they get an email with link 'a.mp3'

The goal is to make it so if a user purchases multiple items such as 'a' , 'b' , and 'c' it will send the multiple corresponding links 'a.mp3' , 'b.mp3' , 'c.mp3' in the body of the email.

Below is the snippet of code that will send just one at a time:

```
if($item_name == 'a')
{
$digital_product_path = 'a.mp3';
}
if ($item_name == 'b')
{
$digital_product_path = 'b.mp3';
}
if ($item_name == 'c')
{
$digital_product_path = 'c.mp3';
}       
if(strtoupper($payment_status) == 'COMPLETED')
{
    $mail -> Subject  =  'Download File Here';
    $mail -> Body = $digital_product_path;
    $mail -> AddAddress($payer_email, $first_name);
    $mail -> Send();
    $mail -> ClearAddresses();
}
```

Paypal will list each item as:
item_name1
item_name2
item_name3

Comment: Can't you just append `$digital_product_path`?

Comment: `$item_name` is only ever going to be 1 item, so how are you getting a list of the items purchased?

Comment: It is using PayPals item_namex, so I believe every time an item is added it is item_name1, item_name2, item_name3

Comment: So you have to use variable Variable names? That sounds kooky. They are not returned in an array? Can loop it. `$item = "item_name"; $i = 1; echo ${$item . $i};` Hopefully it tells you the count of items and then just for loop it.

Answer (score 0):

Your not appending.
I would find a way to loop through your items and feed them into an array so that you can just iterate the names and update them.

After looking at the code in your jsFiddle, you will want to loop over `$cart_items` a second time:

```
$bodyText = "";
foreach($cart_items as $cart_item){
    $bodyText .= $cart_item['name'] . ".mp3\n";
}  
if(strtoupper($payment_status) == 'COMPLETED'){
    $mail -> Subject  =  'Download File Here';
    $mail -> Body = $bodyText;
    $mail -> AddAddress($payer_email, $first_name);
    $mail -> Send();
    $mail -> ClearAddresses();
}
```

Comment: Hello Twisty, When I do this, it only will send the last item_name to come threw on the list

Comment: Need a better example to provide a better answer.

Comment: Hey Twisty, here is a jsfiddle with all the code I am working with https://jsfiddle.net/b43m9txc/

Comment: jsfiddle cannot parse PHP.

Comment: I do not see in there where `$item_name` gets populated.

Comment: I see, The $item_name will be populated with an ipn-listener file and it also has a parse-ipn-data.php file with a long list of all of paypals variables here is the ipn-listener and the parse file https://jsfiddle.net/p9coz756/ https://jsfiddle.net/61k2k7Ln/

Comment: The example you gave does not explain this, nor does it represent this. Please clarify, update question with more details. What error are you getting? What is some sample data you'd expect and what is the an example of the output?

Comment: Hey Twisty, When a user purchases items through a cart the cart sends paypal the item_name (and other variables like address, email, ect). Paypals IPN service then sends the raw data to the ipn listener file using the post method which processes the data and sends the users paypal email a link to their file. It works for one item, but I am trying to make it be able to send multiple links at a time, Just say the user adds 3 items to the cart paypal will list them as item_name1, item_name 2, item_name3 but it will only send a link to item_name3 in the body and not item_name1 and item_name2 link

Comment: Ok so whats a sample of what would be in `$_POST` when you get the data back? You said it's working for 1 item, where is that example?

Comment: Hey Twisty here is an example of a post when 3 items are added to cart https://jsfiddle.net/omvmq5x7/2/

Comment: So the data comes back raw like this!? no JSON or XML nothing??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75456/discussion-between-jeff-and-twisty).